# Git Error After Fresh Install

Tags: git, terminal, html5boilerplate

So I'm trying to run the [createproject.sh script](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/build/createproject.sh) from HTML5 Boilerplate and ran into an error. I saw an issue [documented here](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/issues/397) that seemed relevant and from what I could tell the best way to fix it was to upgrade to the latest git. So I grabbed git from google code (git-1.7.5.4-x86_64-leopard) and ran the installer. Now when I try and run the shell script I wind up with this error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent /Users)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

I'm running a mac with snow leopard and filevault enabled (didn't think this mattered but thought I'd mention it). I've used the uninstall script provided in the dmg to uninstall it and try reinstalling. I've also tried using the other version of git provided by google code (i386) but to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about "HTML5 Boilerplate", but the first command in that script seems to be a git rev-parse, which will only work inside a git repo. Are you running this script in a directory or subdirectory of a local git repo?

Specifically, the script indicates you should run it from `html5-boilerplate/build`, where I assume `html5-boilerplate` would be your local clone of the github repo that you linked. The steps you would take to do it from scratch would go something like:

```
cd <projects dir>
git clone git://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate.git
cd html5-boilerplate/build
chmod +x createproject.sh
./createproject.sh
```

Comment: Yep, I'm running it inside html5-boilerplate/build which I downloaded from the linked repo.

Comment: @Jeff: "downloaded" or "cloned"? Is there a directory named ".git" in your html5-boilerplate directory? If not, then it's not a git repo, and that script won't work.

Comment: Nope, no directory named git just a .gitignore file (I believe I'm showing my git ignorance :)). So what do I need to do to get the repo?

Comment: Got it working now. Thanks for all your help! Now I just need to learn git and bash.